# Rebol Script Error: Alias word is already in use: f whereas it isn't true

Tags: rebol

I have defined these alias in user.r

```
alias 'powershell "pw"
alias 'explorer "o"
alias 'open-program-files "pf"
alias 'cmd "dos"
alias 'edituser "eu"
alias 'run-firefox "fx"
alias 'run-firefox "f"
```

When launching rebol it shows

```
** Script Error: Alias word is already in use: f
** Near: alias 'run-firefox "f"
```

This is not true, in fact when I type source f it says undefined:

```
>> source f
f: undefined
>>
```

So why this message ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, REBOL's **ALIAS** has a severe weakness, at least in R2: *it works only globally.*

So if **any** process has used a word already, it is not available for ALIASing.

Now, you have not defined it. But if you check the total works already defined when you start a fresh console, you may be surprised to see there are several thousand of them:

```
 print length? first system/words
```

And (at least with the version of R2 I just tried it on), that includes the word **f**:

```
find first system/words 'f
```

Even though **f** has no current value, the mere fact that it has been previously uses stops it being used with **ALIAS**.

**ALIAS** is a strong candidate for removal in R3 because of this (and other) limitations in its use.

Comment: Hi thanks that's interesting. If it removed from R3, hope it will get back later with a more robust version because it would be a missing feature compared to Powershell aliases as Rebol is typically good for "Admin Development Model" see http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/01/the-admin-development-model-and-send-snippet.aspx

Comment: There's a detailed discussion of the future of ALIAS here:
http://www.rebol.net/r3blogs/0242.html
It still has some chance of surviving in a better state under R3.

Comment: "I am one of the people who have only used ALIAS enough to produce bug reports.... " :D

Well I seem to have encountered another weird bug : when I load a script which create a function which call an alias. Not sure it always happen systematically will have to check again.

Answer (score 0):

As the Rebol dictionary [says](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/walias.html): **Be careful not to confuse alias with setting another word to the same value.**

`alias` is another overlooked feature of Rebol. If you just need to add new names to reference existing global values (including functions), you can just do it directly without `alias`:

```
pw:  :powershell
o:   :explorer
pf:  :open-program-files
dos: :cmd
eu:  :edituser
fx:  :run-firefox
f:   :run-firefox
```

`alias` will allow you to create a new symbol which will behave identically to the original one. We are talking here about symbols `spelling` equivalence, not words `meaning` equivalence (the eventually referred value). One of the most useful usage for aliasing, is translation of words which can be used as drop-in replacements for the original ones. For example:

```
>> alias 'monday "lundi"
== lundi
>> 'monday = 'lundi
== true
>> find [friday monday sunday] 'monday
== [monday sunday]
>> find [friday monday sunday] 'lundi
== [monday sunday]
```

As you can see, using an aliased word, allows you to create different spellings for the same word, so aliases can be processed by the same code *without having to change it*.

Aliased words could also be useful to create shortcut words for some dialects, though I do not know any dialect of Rebol so far which leveraged that feature.

PS: `lundi` is the French word for `monday`.